# How do I create sql query for searching partial matches?

Tags: sql, keyword

I have a set of items in db .Each `item` has a `name and a description`.I need to implement a `search` facility which takes a number of keywords and returns distinct items which have at least one of the keywords matching a word in the name `or` description.

for example
I have in the db ,three items

```
1.item1 : 
    name : magic marker
    description: a writing device which makes erasable marks    on whiteboard

2.item2:
    name: pall mall cigarettes
    description: cigarette named after a street in london

3.item3:
    name: XPigment Liner
    description: for writing and drawing
```

A search using keyword 'writing' should return magic marker and XPigment Liner

A search using keyword 'mall' should return the second item

I tried using the `LIKE` keyword and `IN` keyword separately ,..
For `IN` keyword to work,the query has to be

```
SELECT DISTINCT FROM mytable WHERE name IN ('pall mall cigarettes')
```

but

```
SELECT DISTINCT FROM mytable WHERE name IN ('mall')
```

will return 0 rows

I couldn't figure out how to make a query that accommodates both the name and description columns and allows partial word match..

Can somebody help?

**update:**

I created the table through hibernate and for the description field, used javax.persistence @Lob annotation.Using psql when I examined the table,It is shown

```
...
 id           | bigint                      | not null
 description  | text                        |  
 name         | character varying(255)      | 
...
```

One of the records in the table is like,

```
id | description | name 
21 | 133414      | magic marker
```

Comment: You need to use LIKE rather than IN.  IN is used for finding out values from a set.  LIKE should be used for partial string comparisons.

Comment: First, you need to figure out what table the textual description is stored in.

Comment: is there any way to find out that?I am using postgres..couldn't find much using the /d commands

Answer (score 29):

First of all, this approach won't scale in the large, you'll need a separate index from words to item (like an inverted index).

If your data is not large, you can do

```
SELECT DISTINCT(name) FROM mytable WHERE name LIKE '%mall%' OR description LIKE '%mall%'
```

using `OR` if you have multiple keywords.

Comment: You need `select distinct name from...`

Comment: You should be aware of case sensitivity as well.

Comment: In the db,I am storing description as a javax.persistence.Lob type..So,the db(postgres) table has a number (133414 etc) as the field content..The 'description LIKE '%something%' fails to return a match..Any idea how to deal with this?

Answer (score 6):

This may work as well.

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable
WHERE CHARINDEX('mall', name) > 0
  OR CHARINDEX('mall', description) > 0
```