# Partial search using php and sql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a search bar for my `Photos` SQL table. When the user hits the search button, I create an array of all the key words entered in the search bar spilt on spaces. I want to return the photos, whose title or credit matches those key words and they do not have to be exact matches (i.e. for a photo titled "Summer 2016", a search for "summer", "2016", or "Summer" will return that photo).

**Photos Table**

```
Photos(
    id int(6) primary key,
    title varchar(150),
    credit varchar(150)
);
```

**PHP**

```
if($validate_search === true) {
  if(isset($_POST['search'])){ 
       $search_fields = explode(" ", $_POST['search_field']); //returns array of search fields

  }
}
```

Based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270134/checking-value-in-an-array-inside-one-sql-query-with-where-clause), I could use `$query="SELECT * FROM posts WHERE Photos IN ({implode(',', $search_fields})";`. But this means the user has to search for the exact title/credit.

Based on another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172947/how-do-i-create-sql-query-for-searching-partial-matches), I could do `SELECT DISTINCT(title) FROM Photos WHERE title LIKE '%$search_fields[1]%' OR credit LIKE '%$search_fields[1]%`, but I can only return the matches for one key word. How do I do partial search using PHP and SQL?

Comment: What database extension are you using?

Comment: What do you mean by database extension? I'm using `$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM Photos");` and phpMyAdmin as a database GUI

Comment: So the answer was `mysqli_`

Comment: @RiggsFolly yupp okay do you have a possible solution to my question?